# codeception assertTrue() equivalent?

Tags: codeception

I've gone through the documentation several times, and through the source, and it doesn't work.

I'm looking for the Codeception equivalent of PHPUnit's "this->assertTrue($var)".

According to the documentation, just like that is should work, but it doesn't, "undefined method". Which helper, module or whatever do I have to activate?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to call assertTrue?

Answer (score 13):

Did you enabled the module 'asserts' in the corresponding suite.yml file? Like:

```
class_name: UnitTester
    modules:
        enabled: [Asserts, UnitHelper]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I wrote in the tests/_helpers/WebHelper.php
(note: WebHelper must be enabled in the .yml)

```
class WebHelper extends \Codeception\Module {

    /**
     * @param bool $a
     */
    function seeTrue( $a ) {
        $this->assertTrue( $a );
    }
}
```

Then, I ran

```
php codecept.phar build
```

And now I can write

```
$I->seeTrue(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just call

```
\PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue (...);
```

Comment: I did that, but things that get tested like this are not visible in the codeception report that gets created. Enable-ing Asserts will do that.